# diff consuming huge amount of memory and cpu

Tags: text-processing, diff

I have two files, **all.txt** (525,953,272 records) and **subset.txt** (525,298,281 records). Each record is nothing but a 17-digit ASCII integer. Both files have been sorted, and duplicate records within each file have been removed. Every value in **subset.txt** also exists in **all.txt**. I wish to find the records in **all.txt** that are not in **subset.txt**.

I'm trying to run a `diff` between these two files, thinking it will write out the rows that are in **all.txt** but not in **subset.txt**. The machine has 64GB of memory. The `diff` has been running for a half hour and currently has acquired about 75% of the memory.

Can anyone speculate on what might be going on, and whether there are arguments to `diff` that might help? Is this just not what `diff` was meant to do, and is there a different approach I should use?

Comment: `525953272 × 17 bytes × 2 ≈ 16 GiB` and `64 × 0.75 / 16 = 3`. As a starting point. Not unlikely a diff utility manages to use 2x. What `diff` ? Something like `diff --version`

Comment: Did you consider writing a simple program to compute that. Take into account that each file is sorted. You'll advance linearly on both files at different paces. (Take inspiration from mergesort, if you don't see what I mean)

Comment: See also `comm`

Comment: @user367890
$ diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1
Copyright (C) 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - comm appears to do exactly what I need. Give it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone speculate on what might be going on, and whether there are
>   arguments to diff that might help? Is this just not what diff was
>   meant to do, and is there a different approach I should use?

This is not what `diff` was meant to do; when the inputs have been sorted (as your have), the tool for the job is `comm`.

```
$ seq 10 15 > subset.txt
$ seq 10 20 > all.txt
$ comm -13 subset.txt all.txt
16
17
18
19
20
```

The [options to `comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) are a little unusual in that they turn *off* output. Column 1 has lines that are unique to file 1; column 2 has lines that are unique to file 2; and column 3 has lines that are "comm"on to both. By using options `-13` we are asking comm to show us lines that are only in "all.txt".

Answer (score 0):

`diff` might not be the most suitable tool to do that. I would try to write a simple script which does specifically what you want.

**All in memory**

This is a very simple and generic solution. It loads the two files into minimalist memory structures, subtracts the records of `subset.txt` from the records of `all.txt` and writes out the remainder.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('diff.txt', 'w') as diff:

    for record in set(open('all.txt', 'r')) - set(open('subset.txt', 'r')):
        diff.write(record)
```

Save that into a file like `create_diff.py`, then `chmod +x create_diff.py` and run it in the directory where your two files are.

**Only subset in memory**

If you need to further optimize for a lower memory footprint it would also be possible to do that without loading the entire files into memory, especially `all.txt` does not need to be loaded into memory completely but could just be iterated over once.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

subset_txt = open('subset.txt', 'r')
subset = subset_txt.readlines()
subset_txt.close()

with open('diff.txt', 'w') as diff_txt:
    with open('all.txt', 'r') as all_txt:
        for line in all_txt:
            if line not in subset:
                diff_txt.write(line)
```

**I/O based**

This should be the slowest variant because it's heavily reliant on I/O, but it has a low memory footprint because it doesn't require the entire files to be loaded into memory. It works no matter if your files are sorted / uniqued or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

diff_txt = open('diff.txt', 'w')

with open('all.txt', 'r') as all_txt:
    with open('subset.txt', 'r') as subset_txt:
        for all_line in all_txt:
            found = False

            for sub_line in subset_txt:
                if all_line == sub_line:
                    found = True
                    break

            if found is False:
                diff_txt.write(all_line)
                subset_txt.seek(0)

diff_txt.close()
```

**Only for sorted files without duplicates** <- recommended in your case

If you're sure that both your files are ordered and contain no duplicates this should be the best solution. Both files are only read once and they do not need to be loaded into memory completely.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

diff_txt = open('diff.txt', 'w')

with open('all.txt', 'r') as all_txt:
    with open('subset.txt', 'r') as subset_txt:
        subset_line = subset_txt.readline()

        for all_line in all_txt:
            if all_line == subset_line:
                subset_line = subset_txt.readline()
            else:
                diff_txt.write(all_line)

diff_txt.close()
```